# Converting CSV data from file to JSON

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a csv file that contains csv data separated by ','. I am trying to convert it into a json format. For this I am tyring to extract headers first. But, I am not able to differentiate between headers and the next row.

Here is the data in csv file:

`Start Date ,Start Time,End Date,End Time,Event Title
9/5/2011,3:00:00 PM,9/5/2011,,Social Studies Dept. Meeting
9/5/2011,6:00:00 PM,9/5/2011,8:00:00 PM,Curriculum Meeting`

I have tried csvreader as well but I got stuck at the same issue.
Basically `Event Title` and the date on the next line is not being distinguished.

```
        with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
            first_line = re.sub(r'\s+', '', f.read())
                arr = []
                headers = []
                for header in f.readline().split(','):
                    headers.append(header)
                for line in f.readlines():
                    lineItems = {}
                    for i,item in enumerate(line.split(',')):
                        lineItems[headers[i]] = item
                    arr.append(lineItems)
                print(arr)
                print(headers)
                jsonText = json.dumps(arr)
                print(jsonText)
```

All three print statements give empty result below.

```
[]
['']
[]
```

I expect jsonText to be a json of key value pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `csv.DictReader` to get a list of dicts (each row is a dict) then serialize it.

```
import json
import csv
with open(csvfilepath) as f:
    json.dump(list(csv.DictReader(f)), jsonfilepath))
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, each file has a marker that keeps track of where you are in the file. Once you call `read()`, you have read through the entire file, and all future read or readline calls will return nothing.

So, just delete the line involving `first_line`.